# How to add my own oauth provider for phabricator？

Tags: php, phabricator

I want to add my own oauth provider. After reading [this](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabcontrib/article/adding_new_classes/), I added a PhabricatorFoobarAuthProvider.php in `phabricator/src/applications/auth/provider/` and added a PhutilFoobarAuthAdapter.php in `libphutil/src/auth/` and then executed `arc liberate` seprately. I expected to see Foobar provider to show in this page: `localhost/auth/config/new` but I didn't. What need I do to reach the goal? Am I forgetting some steps? Thanks.

```
I use `install_ubuntu.sh` to install phabricator. The layout is like this:
    phab
    ....install_ubunut.sh
    ....arcanist/
    ....libphutil/
    ....phabricator/
```

Comment: What specifically are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to add my own pirvate oauth server which allows it's users to login into phabricator.

Answer (score 3):

So the english is a tiny bit broken but i'll answer this the best that I can. What I assume you are trying to do is figure out is "how can I add my own Oauth provider?". In doing so you came across this magical function that seems to be doing something but your not sure what.

The PhutilClassMapQuery is essential to understanding phabricator and arcanist. If you `grep -R "PhutilClassMapQuery" .` you will find around 100 different places that it is used. Every place that this is used you as the user are able to load in your own classes that integrate seamlessly with the Phabricator application.

I'll use `PhabricatorAuthProvider` as an example. If you look [here](https://github.com/phacility/phabricator/blob/6c4c93a091fad8ac7f48e886d450860465fa891a/src/applications/auth/provider/PhabricatorAuthProvider.php#L3https://github.com/phacility/phabricator/blob/6c4c93a091fad8ac7f48e886d450860465fa891a/src/applications/auth/provider/PhabricatorAuthProvider.php#L3) you will notice that this is an abstract class. What the that function does is say load in every class that extends the current class of `PhabricatorAuthProvider`. So as an example if you look [here](https://github.com/phacility/phabricator/blob/24845c70b918789be5309f88ed3f6455f5f29748/src/applications/auth/provider/PhabricatorPersonaAuthProvider.php#L3) you can see that this class provides Persona authentication and it does that simply by implementing the needed functions.

I am not going to go through the rest of this but you should be able to figure out the rest based on the above and using this [link](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabcontrib/article/adding_new_classes/) which shows you how to load your classes into Phabricator.

Hope you enjoy. Phabricator is some of the nicest PHP code that you will find.

Comment: Yeah. That's my question. I only want to extend the functions ( add my own oauth server). The links you give me are useful. Thank you so much.

Comment: another question.  for my question, I have added a PhabricatorFoobarAuthProvider.php  in `phabricator/src/applications/auth/provider/`  and added a PhutilFoobarAuthAdapter.php in `libphutil/src/auth/` and then executed `arc liberate`. But I don't see it in  localhost/auth/config/new' page. Which step do I forget? @mschuett

Comment: Hard to say. If you look in the __phutil_class_map__.php do you see the classes you added ?

Comment: You should add your new class in src/extensions then run `arc liberate` to have it show up

Comment: When I put my PhabricatorFoobarAuthProvider.php in `phabricator/src/applications/auth/provider/`  and then execute `arc liberate`, i can find `PhabricatorFoobarAuthProvider` in `__phutil_library_map__.php`, but it still  doesnot work.